# Maxima: How to display partial derivatives in a more condensed way?

Tags: maxima, derivative

I once found a way to display partial derivatives in a more condensed way in maxima. Instead of the partial derivatives being displayed like

```
d f(x)
——————
  dx
```

They were displayed like

```
(f(x))_x
```

or something similar. This is very handy when you have long expressions containing numerous partial derivatives : with the default setting it can sometimes be difficult to read…

It had something to do with setting a maxima global flag to either true or false. Sadly, I am having some trouble finding the syntax again… Could someone enlighten me?

In case you are wondering : yes, I already had a look on the Internet and in Maxima's manual but still can't find the information I am looking for, although I am very certain it must be lying somewhere there…

Comment: The second notation looks more like notation for integration

Comment: @Natecat Just found the answer to my question and indeed it displays it as `(f(x))_x` and not `d_x f(x)`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution #1 : deerivabbrev

Setting the maxima global flag `derivabbrev` to true

```
(%i0) derivabbrev : true;
```

will change the way derivatives are being displayed from

```
(%i1) diff(f(x),x)

         d f(x)
(%o1)    ——————
           dx
```

to

```
(%i1) diff(f(x),x)

(%o1)    (f(x))_x
```

## Solution #2 : pdiff

Another way is to use the positional derivative notation. First load the pdiff library

```
load(pdiff)
```

Not only will that add the positional derivative feature, it will also enable it by default. As a consequence,

```
(%i0) diff(f(x),x)
```

will be rendered as

```
(%o0) f_(1) (x)
```

To disable it, unset the global flag `use_pdiff`

```
(%i1) use_pdiff : false;
```

And of course, to enable it again, set it back to true

```
(%i2) use_pdiff : true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from `derivabbrev`, you can also take a look at `pdiff` (positional derivatives).

```
(%i1) load (pdiff);
(%o1)           /usr/share/maxima/5.39.0/share/pdiff/pdiff.lisp
(%i2) diff(f(x),x);
(%o2)                               f   (x)
                                     (1)
```

There is a description of pdiff in `share/pdiff/pdiff-doc.pdf` in your Maxima installation.

Comment: @Robert_Dodier how do you disable the pdiff display once it has been enabled ?

Comment: RTFM to myself : `use_pdiff : false`

Comment: @Robert_Dodier perhaps you should show all the possible solutions in your answer so that future readers can find all the relevant information at the same place, i.e. `load(pdiff)` + `use_pdiff : false` + `derivabbrev : true`

Comment: And why isn't `pdiff-doc.pdf` in a `doc/` folder? Just being curious… ;)

Comment: Well, there are many things which are not strongly organized in Maxima. This is a consequence of its long history and organic development policy. I certainly agree that many things could be organized better. If you would like to work on putting pdiff and other packages in order, I will give you write permission for the Git repository. Just let me know.

Comment: Ahah perhaps in one year time when I'll be jobless, after the end of my current contract…

Comment: There's no hurry. The Maxima project has been going for almost 50 years ... Whenever you have the time is soon enough.

Comment: Why not : I'll get in touch with you when/if I decide to jump in! ;) . Besides, are you sure you don't want to show all the possible solutions in your answer so that future readers can find all the relevant information at the same place? i.e. `load(pdiff)` + `use_pdiff : false` + `derivabbrev : true`. If not, then I think I'll append it to my own answer.

Comment: You can go ahead and append it to your answer.